# QGIS 2.12.3 Crashes on buffering line vectors

Tags: qgis, vector, buffer, line, qgis-2.12

I'm using QGIS 2.12.3 and I'm trying to create a **buffer of 100 mt around a line vector** using the Vector - Geoprocessing Buffer tool, but qgis crashes at every try. I've already checked that the RS of the vector is the same of the project.
Can anybody give some hint to solve this problem and create the buffer?

Comment: Does it still crash if you use the buffer tools from the _Processing Toolbox_?

Comment: which CRS are you using?

Comment: @Joseph It doesn't crash, but it returns this in the log: 

QgsFeature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

Comment: @iant I'm using WGS84 UTM32N EPSG:32632

Comment: I tried buffering a simple line vector and it works perfectly... is it possible that the error depends on a multipath vector or on an error made in the creation of the line vector?

Comment: Could you also check the geometry validity of your vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGIS has issues with geographic coordinates, you should use Save As and pick a projected CRS such as 27700 british national grid. If that didn't solve it then...

I just had the same problem with a "bad" line vector layer. Hope it's not too late but after trying several workarounds, what I've done was using the MMQGIS plugin > modify > convert geometry type. The resulting layer was perfectly fine